# GLKBaseEffect set Constant color

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, opentk, glkbaseeffect

I want use GLKBaseEffect for coloring my 3DModel.
I created examplar of GLKBaseEffect

```
GLKBaseEffect effect;
```

When i setup OpenGL i write:

```
effect = new GLKBaseEffect();
```

When i draw my figure i use effect:

```
effect.Light0.SpecularColor = new Vector4 (2.5f, 2.5f, 2.5f, 0.1f);
effect.UseConstantColor = true;
effect.Transform.ModelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
effect.PrepareToDraw ();
```

I use ConstantColor for setting color:

```
effect.ConstantColor = new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

But color in model do not change. What i missed?

Comment: effect.MAterial.SpecularColor = new Vector4 (2.5f, 2.5f, 2.5f, 0.1f);

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two causes. I am just learning OpenGL ES 2.0 right now and my answer is limited to what I have just learned so far.

First, maybe your drawing happened before setting base effect.

Second, the context in which you set your base effect might not be made current context before you drew.